# How to get intent content in receiving app when launched with getLaunchIntentForPackage()?

Tags: android

I have an intent filter for receiving intents with a specific URI. When another app opens my app with that specific URI, I use that deeplink/unilink, and redirect in the app using a Flutter plugin, depending on which query parameters are included in the URI.

In AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
        <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"/>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="appspecifictheme" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.myappslandingpage.com" 
                android:pathPrefix="/myappspath" />
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.myappslandingpage.com" 
                android:pathPrefix="/myspecificpathprefix" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is working fine when launching from another app with uri https://www.myappslandingpage.com/myspecificpathprefix/?param1=xxxx&param2=xxxx&param3=xxxx

Now to my issue: another app wants to launch my app using this intent from package manager, and passing the query parameters as extras instead:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("receiving.apps.package.name");

launchIntent.putExtra("param1", "xxxx");
launchIntent.putExtra("param2", "xxxx");
launchIntent.putExtra("param3", "xxxx");

startActivity(launchIntent);
```

**Question 1**: When I launch my app from another app using above code, and the app is opened, but how do I get the content from the intent? I have tried using getIntent() in my MainActivity's onCreate(), but it doesn't seem to be working (stringExtras and other data in the intent is null).

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    checkIntent(getIntent());
    FlutterMain.startInitialization(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

void checkIntent(Intent i) {
    final String param1 = i.getStringExtra("param1");
    final String param2 = i.getStringExtra("param2");
    final String param3 = i.getStringExtra("param3");

    final Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
    if(extras != null) {
      for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
        L.d(TAG, "checkIntent() extra: " + key + " : " + (extras.get(key) != 
        null ? extras.get(key) : "NULL"));
        //Above logs nothing - there are no keys in extras.
      }
    }

    if(param1 != null) {
      //Do something
    } else {
      L.d(TAG,"checkIntent(): param1 is null");
    }
  }
```

I have also tried adding URI to the intent using launchIntent.setData("uri") before running startActivity() from the other app, and changing the intent filter in my receiving app as below, but getIntent().getData() in MainActivity also returns null.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

**Question 2**: If I find a way to receive the intent and get the stringExtras, is there a simple way to "transform" that intent so that it is interpreted the same way as if the app was opened with a deeplink?

Comment: In onCreate(): checkIntent(getIntent()); Dont do that as first statement. No setContentView() to do?

Comment: intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

Comment: @blackapps: UI is written in Flutter so I guess FlutterMain.startInitialization(this) replaces setContentView(). 

intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION.VIEW) made it work! Unfortunately, the app that wants to interact with my app is not able to set action (their implementation only allows editing extras) - is there any way for the receiving app to get intent with the default action (ACTION.MAIN)?

Comment: Well did you put that in instead of action view? And please post complete activity definition from manifest. I suppose that both apps are programmed by you.

Comment: @blackapps getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage() seems to return action main by default. I don't have access to the other app, all I know is that they are only able to use getLaunchIntentForPackage(), and set stringExtras before launching my app. (I have built another app for testing purposes, that's how I know it's working when setting action view). I have updated my post to include entire activity.

Comment: Why do you think that other apps (not one of your apps) using getLaunchIntentForPackage() to start your app would putExtra() "param1", "param2" and "param3"?  Can you name one app that would do that? I would be very surprised.

Comment: @blackapps The other app will send 3 extras containing order data that my app will act on. They won't actually be named param1, 2, 3 - I renamed them in my example. I just want to know how to get the stringExtra values in my MainActivity from the default intent returned by getLaunchIntentForPackage().

Comment: `The other app will send 3 extras containing order data` Why? My app would not do that. And why are you still asking how to retrieve the parameters if they are there? You do that already with checkIntent().

Comment: @blackapps We have a cooperation with another company, and their users should (by clicking a button in their app) be redirected to our app and access specific functions depending on the values in the extras. The details aren’t that important. Maybe I’ve been unclear - the issue is that i.getStringExtra() in my code returns null, unless I change action to view (as you suggested). Since the other company can’t set another action for the intent, I need to somehow edit my manifest so that I can get the stringExtras from the intent returned by getLaunchIntentForPackage().

Comment: You want to extract key-value pairs form the extras from an intent. I understand that you have a valid intent (getIntent() returns not null). Is it that you dont know the key names that you cannot extract the string extras? Or what is the real problem? You can just log all the key-value pais that are contained in an intent and hence know what is available.

Comment: `I need to somehow edit my manifest so that I can get the stringExtras from the intent` No. I do not think so. Your checkIntent() should do it with the right key's.

Comment: Just did some tests and without extra intent-filter's for the receiving activity all parameters come in (Java).

Comment: @blackapps When I run getLaunchIntentForPackage() from the other app with intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW), I get all values from the extras in my checkIntent(). If I run the exact same code without setting action - there are no extras in the intent. Did you set action to view in your test?

Comment: @blackapps when I don't set action, below code in checkIntent() returns nothing, but when I set action to VIEW, all keys and values are logged.

`final Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
 for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
 
L.d(TAG, "checkIntent() extra: " + key + " : " + (extras.get(key) != null ? extras.get(key) : "NULL"));
       }
      }`

Comment: That is not readable in comments. Please post that normal in code blocks in your post. And... Did you remove all the intent-filtes form that activity for a test? I said i had no extra filters. (Only MAIN, LAUNCHER) And i do not use ACTION_VIEW or ACTION_MAIN.

Comment: @blackapps sorry, added the code in my post. What I meant was: did you edit the intent action before running startActivity(intent) from the other app? Or did you start the activity with the default intent returned from getLaunchIntentForPackage()? I tried removing all intent filters in the receiving app (except MAIN/LAUNCHER), still same result...

Comment: I did/do it like you do it in your post.

Comment: Ok, I finally figured out what the problem was. The package name in AndroidManifest was not the same as the application id (which I used to launch my app). Should have thought of that!! Thanks for your perseverance @blackapps, appreciate your time!